# maximum amount of users on ORiNOCO® AP‐700 and AP‐4000 and Cisco 1200 and 1140?

Tags: cisco, wifi, users

I'm doing a study on how providers can increase usage of public hotspots, and found that they are using ORiNOCO® AP‐700,AP‐4000 ,Cisco 1200 and 1140 wifi access points.
What is the maximum amount of users these devices can handle simultaneously?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about specs on the ORiNOCO devices but the Cisco devices don't have "published" maximum association specifications that I've ever seen. You'll find various documents (like [this Aironet FAQ, under the question about wireless handsets per AP](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/wireless/ps430/products_qanda_item09186a008009483e.shtml)) that give some vague numbers but I'm not aware of hard-and-fast published maximums. I suspect that any maximums you find published will relate to the APs ability to track associations and will be *highly* optimistic.

The amount of traffic that associated mobile units are moving and their data rate is going to determine the amount of free wireless bandwidth. I would guess that contention on the wireless media (the air) is going to be a problem long before the ability of those APs (which are all reasonably high-end) to handle the number of associations.

I use a rule-of-thumb with non-beamforming omnidirectional APs of no more than 20 clients per AP for a good user experience. APs with more antennas and / or radios (Xirrus, Ruckus, etc) will be able to handle significantly more. I'm talking about a scenario with Windows roaming user profiles, redirected "My Documents" folders, etc-- a wired network replacement in a corporate environment. For Internet access only you could probably double that number and see reasonable performance (provided your wired layer 2 and Internet uplink can handle it).

[Planning for large numbers of wifi clients](https://serverfault.com/questions/72767/why-is-internet-access-and-wi-fi-always-so-terrible-at-large-tech-conferences) is still a bit of an art. Things have gotten better since Joel's question (hard to believe that was almost two years ago) and beamforming APs can make covering large numbers of clients a lot easier than "dumb" APs of just a couple of years ago.

Edit:

There's a really good recently-published article at Tom's Hardware that speaks to the performance of APs with increasing numbers of clients: [Why Your Wi-Fi Sucks And How It Can Be Helped](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/wi-fi-performance,2985.html)

In that article they subject a variety of APs to a load of 60 clients and graph the results. You can get a feel, from the charts and the commentary, about what happens when the number of clients simultaneously associated with an AP does to performance.