# Portable wifi set up with 100s of connections

Tags: wifi, apple

I'm making a system that can connect all the smart phones in an audience to my server. It's for a fun open-source project that can create animations and interactive games. More info on my G+ https://plus.google.com/112390830769420730223/posts/WHBLqdKtM1G

I need :

- A wifi system that can handle 100s of connections but only a local network - no internet required
- Audience members will be in a fairly confined space and connect only their iPhones and Android phones
- Security isn't an issue so it can be an open network
- Ideally something carryable and easy to set up.

I've been told that I should look into setting up a mesh network, would the Airport Extreme's relay mechanism be good for that? Or would it be better to get multiple access points and a controller? I'd rather not have lots of cables so a mesh solution would be better.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: this question may help you: http://serverfault.com/questions/72767/why-is-internet-access-and-wi-fi-always-so-terrible-at-large-tech-conferences

Comment: Yeah I've actually been in touch with Sean about this. My set up is similar but also different in some ways - I don't need internet, and I only need to cover one large room. Also I won't have much time for set up. I'm interested to hear from anyone who has set up a mesh network with multiple relays.

Comment: Not sure if you still care but I found this in Unanswered.  :)  Why not just use 3 residential routers with DD-WRT on different channels and SSIDs?  Plug two into the switchports of the first and set them as AP only so only the first serves DHCP.  Have the first offer up a x.x.x.x/23 network of IPs.  You could point into areas of the crowd and say 'You here connect to SSID1/2/3' and that would spread the wireless connections across 3 bands and 3 SSIDs but they'd be on one network and subnet.